# How to develop a map with bubble in angular where bubble would represent the server locations

Tags: angular, maps

I am new to `angular` and got some work, develop a `Map` which has bubble on it. Where bubble will represent the server locations, bubble green color represent the `completed` upload, bubble orange color `inprogress` and red color would indicate `failed` upload on server.

*These servers has 20+ locations in db. I am not sure if I should use world map to show these 20 locations or I need to create a map with only only 20 locations.*

Planning to use `chart.js` library but don't know it is providing maps with bubble.

suggest the way to start. this image look similar to my requirement

[image: this image is similar to my requirement]

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Leaflet js.

https://leafletjs.com/examples.html

https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html